# Heron's formula vs 'complex cross products' for triangle area?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles, area

I would like to prove the equivalence between the following two ways of calculating the area of the triangle between points $\;p\;$, $\;q\;$, and $\;r\:$ in the complex plane.

First, there is Heron's formula, $$
\tag{0} \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$$ where $$
a = \left| p-q \right| \\
b = \left| q-r \right| \\
c = \left| r-p \right| \\
s = {1 \over 2} (a+b+c)
$$

Second, there is $$
\tag{1} \left| {1 \over 2i} (p \times q + q \times r + r \times p) \right|
$$ where $$
x \times y \;=\; {1 \over 2} (\overline{x}y - x\overline{y})
$$ is the 'complex cross product' of complex numbers $\;x,y\;$.  (See my question [Complex integral to determine area inside of parameterized closed curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3662234/11994) for the reference that gave me $(1)$, by adding the 'directed area' of triangles $\;\triangle 0 p q\;$, $\;\triangle 0 q r\;$, and $\;\triangle 0 r p\;$.)

How do I prove $(0)$ and $(1)$ are equivalent?  It seems it should be a fairly simple calculation, but I've tried multiple approaches and cannot yet get anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer : I will not try here to connect your formulas (0) and (1)

(see Edit below for connections between Heron's formula and complex numbers).

I will just show here that (1) can be considered in a very plain way.

Indeed, (1) is a direct consequence of the Laplace expansion of the following determinant :

$$A=\frac{i}{4}\begin{vmatrix}p&q&r\\\overline{p}&\overline{q}&\overline{r}\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}\tag{I}$$

with respect to its last row.

(I) can be obtained from the equivalent rather classical [formula (16) in this reference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html) with real coordinates :

$$A=\frac12\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\\y_1&y_2&y_3\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}\tag{II}$$

Proof : (II) is related to (I) through the following identity (taking determinants on both sides) :

$$\begin{pmatrix}p&q&r\\\overline{p}&\overline{q}&\overline{r}\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1& \ \ \ i&0\\1&-i&0\\0& \ \ \ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_p&x_q&x_r\\y_p&y_q&y_r\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

**Edit** :

1) Have a look to [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02816.pdf) about Cayley-Menger determinant. It is worth seeing two paragraphs : paragraph $4$ about the fact that Heron's formula can be expressed as a  $4 \times 4$ (Cayley-Menger) determinant, and paragraph $2$ giving a nice proof of Heron's formula using complex numbers.

2) See p. 106 of the following book "Complex Numbers from A to... Z", 2nd Ed., T. Andreescu and D. Andrica, Birkhäuser 2010, for your formula (1) and other formulas.

3) For applications of formula (I), see this [interesting article](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-088/S0025-5718-1964-0167602-8/S0025-5718-1964-0167602-8.pdf) (formula (I) is their formula (4)) and [extensions](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102995570) by the same author.

4) Please note that (I) represents the *oriented* area of the triangle.

5) Formula (1) can be used to express the '$(z,\overline{z})$' equation of the line $[p,q]$ under the form :

$$\begin{vmatrix}p&q&z\\\overline{p}&\overline{q}&\overline{z}\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

(indeed $z$ is aligned with $p,q$ iff the area of triangle $p,q,z$ is zero.)

Thanks to @achille hui for a sign correction in formula (I).

Comment: See the edit I just added.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to show that both these numbers are equal to

$$S=\frac{1}{2}|p-r||p-q|\xi(p-r,p-q)$$

where $\xi(u,v)$ is the sine of the angle between vectors $u,v$ i.e.
 $$\xi(u,v)=\sqrt{1-\frac{\langle u,v\rangle^2}{|u|^2\cdot|v|^2}}$$

First, observe that

$$\langle p-r,p-q\rangle=|p|^2-\langle r,p\rangle-\langle p,q\rangle+\langle r,q\rangle=|p|^2-\frac{1}{2}(-|p-r|^2+|p|^2+|r|^2)-\frac{1}{2}(-|p-q|^2+|p|^2+|q|^2)+\frac{1}{2}(-|r-q|^2+|r|^2+|q|^2)=\frac{1}{2}(|p-r|^2+|p-q|^2-|r-q|^2)=\frac{1}{2}(c^2+a^2-b^2)$$
(Btw it is known as cosine law).

Then,

$$S=\frac{1}{2}|p-r||p-q|\sqrt{1-\frac{\langle p-r,p-q\rangle^2}{|p-r|^2\cdot|p-q|^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{c^2a^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}(c^2+a^2-b^2)\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(2ac-a^2-c^2+b^2)(2ac+a^2+c^2-b^2)}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(b^2-(a-c)^2)((a+c)^2-b^2)}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

On the other hand,

$$|\frac{1}{2}(p\times q+q\times r+r\times p)|=\frac{1}{2}|(p-q)\times (p-r)|$$

I will show that for all $u,v$:
$$|u\times v|=|u||v|\xi(u,v)$$

Indeed,

$$|u\times v|^2=|\frac{1}{2}(\overline{u}v-u\overline{v})|^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(|\overline{u}v|^2+|u\overline{v}|^2-2\langle \overline{u}v,u\overline{v}\rangle \right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(2|u|^2|v|^2-2\left(2\langle u, v\rangle^2-|u|^2|v|^2\right)\right)=|u|^2|v|^2-\langle u,v\rangle^2=(|u||v|\xi(u,v))^2$$

The property
$$\langle \overline{u}v,u\overline{v}\rangle=2\langle u, v\rangle^2-|u|^2|v|^2$$
used above can be proved by writing out real and imaginary parts of $u$ and $v$.